# Passing a matrix to a function and calculate the sum of each row

Tags: c, matrix

How can I pass a matrix to a function and calculate the sum of each row?
This is the function I created but
I'm stuck at here. Please help guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define row 4
#define col 4

int Schum(int A[row][col]){
    int sum, i, j;
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        sum = 0;
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            sum += A[i] [j];  
        }
    } 
    return sum;  
}

int main(){
    int A[row] [col], i, j, sum;
    for (i=0; i<row; i++){
        for (j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("Enter number in [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &A[i] [j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i < row; i++){
        for(j=0; j < col; j++){
            printf("[%d][%d]: %d\t", i, j, A[i][j]); 
            sum = Schum(A);
        } 
        printf("Sum of row%d: %d\n", i+1, sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Schum function is incorrect. You do not need to loop over all elements of the matrix to find the sum of a given row. You are also incorrectly calling the Schum function for every element of the matrix from main(). It should only be called once for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one. Passing the row number that you want to sum its columns and calling Schum function outside of column iteration but inside of row iteration are enough to achieve your objective.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define row 4
#define col 4

int Schum(int A[row][col], int rowParam){
  int sum = 0, j;
  for (j = 0; j < col; j++){
    sum += A[rowParam][j];  
  }

  return sum;
}

int main(){ 
  int A[row][col], i, j, sum;

  for (i=0; i < row; i++){
    for (j=0; j < col; j++){
      printf("Enter number in [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (i=0; i < row; i++){
    for(j=0; j < col; j++){
      printf("[%d][%d]: %d\t", i, j, A[i][j]); 
    } 

    sum = Schum(A, i);
    printf("Sum of row%d: %d\n", i+1, sum);
  }
}
```